How to use 'or' in rego OPA
I have a list, and I want to check that every string in the list contains a substring, such as 'a' or 'b'.
allow {
   every x in str_list {
     contains(lower(x), 'a') or contains(lower(x), 'b')
    }
}

The Rego language does not have a or keyword.
How can the condition be achieved?

This question is similar to: OR in Open Policy Agent (union behavior). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
